# In Angular 13/typescript how to replace form.submit() with FormData and CORS

Tags: angular, forms, cors

I tried replacing a call to form.submit() with FormData and I get CORS errors no matter what I have tried. The code is inside a service.
This works:

```
   const form = document.createElement('form');
      form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
      form.setAttribute('action', theUrl);

      for (const key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key) && params[key]) {
          const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', key);
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', params[key]);

          form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
      }
      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
```

However, this doesn't (I get a CORS missing header error):

```
      var formData: any = new FormData();
      for (const key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key) && params[key]) {
          formData.append(key, params[key]);
        }
      }

      let clientHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Type': 'formData',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      });

      return this.httpClient.post(theUrl,formData,{ headers: clientHeaders })
        .pipe(tap(
          (response) => {
            console.log(response);
          },
          ()=>{
            console.error(Error);
             });
          }
        )
        )
```

Also this doesn't work(same error):

```
      var formData: any = new FormData();
      for (const key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key) && params[key]) {
          formData.append(key, params[key]);
        }
      }

      const data = new URLSearchParams(formData);
      return fetch(theUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
        mode: 'cors' });
```

Details, CORS error(chrome):

**Ensure CORS response header values are valid**

```
A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request .
To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values.
Note that if an opaque response is sufficient, the request's mode can be set to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled; that way CORS headers are not required but the response content is inaccessible (opaque).
1 request
Request Status  Preflight Request (if problematic)  Header  Problem Invalid Value (if available)
redirect    blocked     Access-Control-Allow-Origin Missing Header
```

Details, form field name:key, and form field value:params[key]

Do you know any way other way than having to create a fake hidden form in current document, just to send some field values AND
not get the CORS errors?
Again, in Angular 13 and typescript web app project.

Comment: You'll get cors if you submit a request via XHR/fetch. This is not a frontend issue but a backend. Your back should allow those requests.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the backend server :(.

Comment: you then have to use a frontend proxy, which will call the external backend.

Comment: Never send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in a request, this is a response header. And what does the `Type` header do? I suspect these unnecessary headers are the reason for the CORS error you observe.

Comment: I tried without those headers too, same result.

Comment: To be more clear: this is an application which is deployed to many customers. Apparently the customers don't want and/or agree with any change so I can't add proxy servers and so on. The only thing that can be deployed is the Angular application.